# Should a business create social media accounts for founders in addition to a company social media account?

Tags: blog, social-media, social-networking

Is it a good idea to have a company profile on social media as well as individual accounts of people that are involved in the company, for example the founders, CEO, etc.?

I am thinking of a business that is in a specific niche, let us say for example bicycles (and everything else related to bicycles). It has a website (e-commerce and blog)and social media profiles on all the major social media channels like `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Google+`, `Instagram`, etc. This just for the business side of things.

The blog posts are written by 2 people - they both are founders of this bicycle company. At the end of each post (as is the norm) is a photo of the author and a link to his social media profiles (for example to `Google+`).

So this brings me back to my question. Do you need social media profiles for the company and the founders?

I just can't get my head around things. Something tells me that you need to separate your business profile for the profiles of the founders, each 1 has their own presence.

I also read in a book that you need to be intimate as possible - when reaching out to people (for example in forums) that you need respond as a person, and not a business. This is why I am thinking of the 2 separate profiles.

So if this is the case how do you differentiate between the 2 profiles seeing that you have to generate the content on the social media profiles? What would you post on the one and not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe its bad idea to have separate social profiles for business name and founder name. You are right on forums, communities and even social media, profiles with a person name helps to connect with other people easily. You have to make sure that anything related to your business will be shared on your business social profiles and then from individual profiles you can share or like it further.

Comment: Thanks. Can you maybe give me an example of each? The business will post something regarding a product special, but won't the founder and CEO do exactly the same? I don't know how to differentiate who posts what?

Comment: HI..the founder can post if their is something product special, there is no hard and fast rule on social media but if you will post a product special from your business account, its look more sound. Hope you understand